# $X_1, X_2$ iid Uniform on $[0,1]$, find the distribution of $Z = X_1 - 2X_2$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I took intro Probability last year and this question came up on my stats homework. I mostly understand the cdf method and the convolution formula, but I'm confused about how to split it up and pick bounds. Here is what I have so far.

$Z=X_1-2X_2$ follows a $ U[-2,0]$ distribution.

$$P(Z<z)=P(X_1-2X_2<z)=P(X_1<z+2X_2)$$

I can see the range of $Z$ is should be $[-2,1]$, and when I plug $z+2X_2$ in for the integral I get $X_2$ as a part of the cdf for $Z$, which doesn't seem right to me. We haven't done anything like this for this class, so I'm confused why it's on my homework, but thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Let $Y=2X_2$

\begin{align}
P(Z < z) &= P(X_1 < z + 2X_2) \\
&= P(X_1 < z+ Y)\\
&= \int_{0}^2 P(X_1 < z+Y|Y=y)f_Y(y) \,dy\\
&=\frac12\int_{0}^2P(X_1<z+y)\,dy
\end{align}

Try to evaluate the expression.

Comment: Should the limits not be $\int_0^2$ since you're integrating over $Y$ which is distributed $U[0,2]$?

Comment: oops, you are right. thanks!